# Angular 2 : Send image to node server

Tags: image, file, express, angular, upload

I'm writting my own boilerplate with express, and js framework for front-end(Angular2) I want to include profile picture options.

So now, from the input file i encode to base 64 the picture, i send the base 64 image to the server, i decode base 64 image and store it as a picture.

For displaying image to the client, i was thinking to encoded my image store in my server to base 64 and sending it to front-end and display it under img src=""

It is good or bad implementation ?

For bigger file (video, files), what did you recommend ?

Thank's

Comment: Can you share how you upload files to node? I tried a bunch of libraries that don't work. (ng-file-upload, n2-uploader)